# Java how to catch ALL run time errors

Tags: java

I've built a socket server which logs all it proccesses in a text file.

For now, the server runs in the background and has no UI.

Is there a way for me to catch ALL run time errors (not just the ones throwing exeptions) include null pointers etc. and log it to a file for monitoring?

Comment: What sort of run-time error doesn't throw an exception? Can you give a few examples?

Comment: You need to write the logging statements (according to your logger setting) to see what you want to see in your log file(s).

Comment: catch (RuntimeException re) catches all errors.

Comment: @Mankarse not all error make you use try/catch

Comment: You could try having a look at [ThreadGroup#uncaughtException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable))

Comment: @stackmonster `RuntimeException` doesn't nearly cover all errors, unless you've got a twisted definitin of error that doesn't include `IOException` or  `OutOfMemoryError`, among many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is simple to catch anything that can be thrown in Java. You just need to catch the base class of everything throwable:

```
try {
  ... my code ...
catch (Throwable t) {
  ... process it ...
}
```

A note on terminology: everything that can be thrown in Java is called an "exception", not only the exceptions extending from the `Exception` class. This is an unfortunate choice of class names, possibly due to a late decision in Java design to introduce a superclass to `Exception`.

Comment: Late compared to what? On what evidence?

Comment: @EJP No evidence, it is my guess. If you have a better guess or evidence, please provide it for my education.

Comment: but then i have to wrap all my code and classes inside that right ?

Comment: I would hope you have a central place where you dispatch work from, like where you accept client requests. You need the catch only at that one place.

Comment: Some more advice in this respect: you must in fact **ensure** you don't catch any exceptions at other places in code. If checked exceptions give you trouble, write `try { ... } catch (RuntimeException e) { throw e; } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }`. This will ensure you let any unchecked exception through, but wrap any checked exception into `RuntimeException`.